# Cannot read full user profiles MS Graph while having the needed scopes

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using the GraphServiceClient in my code to access multiple endpoints for data. I have a service account who logs in with Azure AD, with the following scopes: `Group.Read.All`, `User.Read.All`, `Mail.Read`.

However, with these needed scopes I cannot [get the MailFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) for a users profile or a birthdate from the user. It gives the following error:

```
ServiceException: Code: -2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException.
```

The delegated permissions in Azure AD have already granted by admin (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnoel.jpg).

Example MailFolders:

```
var result = await client
  .Users[user.Id]
  .MailFolders
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

This is the error that came back:

```
ServiceException: 
   Code: ErrorAccessDenied
   Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

Can I not access other users profiles or am I missing something else?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to combine multiple questions into a single post. Jason covered your mailbox question but you also mentioned an issue fetching birthdate. These are two different workloads with different permission scopes. I suggest posting the user profile question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Mail.Read` as a delegated permission (meaning you've logged in with a user), then you can only read your own mail, **even if someone has given you permissions to their mailbox**. In order to read other mailboxes, you need to request the `Mail.Read.Shared` permission.

If you have `Mail.Read` as an application permission (meaning no logged in user to your app, using the client credentials flow), then you can read all mailboxes in your org.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the question is already answered here.
Even when you app has admin consent to do something it does not override the Exchange delegate permission if you know what I mean.

You would need that specific user's token or try to access it as a user who is delegated in Exchange online.